# Any proxy or code that allows a browser to use http on https web server?

Tags: reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I have a web app that will reside in a secure site (HTTPS) that needs to access other sites using http using javascript libraries.

Due to very valid security concerns this is not allowed in modern browsers but I can't control the other http sites that I need to access.

My question is: **What are my best options for this (and only) particular case?** I would like to be pointed in the direction of a minimal solution to the problem if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Nearly every browser used supports HTTPs. The nice this is that TLS is highly customizable, and so long as they haven't removed support for old ciphers the older browsers can still connect.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with Titanium Web Proxy.
Thanks